# Swift: Generic's type protocol not being recognized

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Long time listener, first time caller.

I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type MyClass<Model<A>, OtherClass> to expected argument type MyClass<Protocol, OtherClass>`

Despite the fact that `MyClass<T>` conforms to `Protocol`

I've attached a snippet that can be run in Playgrounds that resembles what I am actually trying to achieve.

```
protocol DisplayProtocol {
    var value: String { get }
}

class DataBundle<T: CustomStringConvertible>: DisplayProtocol {
    var data: T
    var value: String {
        return data.description
    }

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Mapper<DisplayProtocol, Data> {
    // ...
}

class MapperViewModel<Data> {
    let mapper: Mapper<DisplayProtocol, Data>

    init(mapper: Mapper<DisplayProtocol, Data>) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }
}

let dataBundle = DataBundle<Int>(data: 100)
let mapper = Mapper<DataBundle<Int>, Bool>()
let viewModel = MapperViewModel<Bool>(mapper: mapper) // <- This fails w/error
```

Is this the expected behavior? If it is it feels like its breaking the contract of allowing me to have the `DisplayProtocol` as a type in `Mapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that Swift generics are invariant in respect to their arguments. Thus `MyClass<B>` is not compatible with `MyClass<A>` even if `B` is compatible with `A` (subclass, protocol conformance, etc). So yes, unfortunately the behaviour is the expected one.

In your particular case, if you want to keep the current architecture, you might need to use protocols with associated types and type erasers.

Comment: I see - that's a bummer. Thanks for answer tho!

Comment: @YourMaineMan it's a bummer, but it's also understandable given the fact that each generic specialization is a different type